# How can I use the "Enter Key" for getKey in Graphics.py

Tags: python, graphics

I can say - (if key = 'Left') or (if key = 'Right'), but for some reason i can't say - (if key = 'Enter'). Why isn't this working? Can I not use the enter key for getKey in graphics.py?

Comment: Is this the Graphics.py you're referring to?: mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: @castle-bravo yes.

Comment: Have you tried other aliases of `Enter`? Perhaps it's called `Return`?

Comment: Can you modify your question to include some of your code, along with a description of the error you're getting? The more information you include, the easier it is to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I had the same problem and looked through the graphics.py module to find out how it worked. Looks like it uses tkinter's key input system, supported keys are here [https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm][1]

As for my code, this worked:

```
keyString = win.getKey()
if(keyString == "Return"):
    #do your thing here
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The key value comes from the `_onkey` event listener:

```
def _onKey(self, evnt):
    self.lastKey = evnt.keysym
```

You can see the valid keysyms for Tk [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm).

This lists `Return` as a valid type, as well as `KP_Enter` for the keypad enter key.